# JSON Javascript & HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am a grade 11 level computer programmer and encountered some difficulties when trying to complete our JSON assignment. The goal is to save an object to local storage, but my html and js do not do so. Instead, nothing happens at all. All feedback is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="JDOS.js">
</script>
    <title>Announcements Storage</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Add New Announcement</legend>
            Title:<br>
            <input required id="title" type="text"><br>
            Category:<br>
            <input required id="category" type ="text"><br>
            Creator:<br>
            <input required id="creator" type="text"><br>
            Type:
            <select required id='type' name="type" >
                <option value="Event">Event</option>
                <option value="Reminder">Reminder</option>
                <option value="General">General</option>
            </select><br>
            Date and Time:<br>
            <input required id="date" type="date"><br>
            <input required id="time" type="time"><br>
            Sex:<br>
            <select required id='sex'>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="All">All</option>
            </select><br>
            Grade:<br>
            <input required id='grade' type='text'><br>
            Message:<br>
            <textarea required id="message" rows="10" cols="50">Type 
            announcement here</textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" onclick="createAnnouncement()" value="Post">
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <div id="showAnnouncement"></div>
</body>
</html>

Javascript begins here:

function createAnnouncement() {
var title= document.getElementById('title').value;
var category= document.getElementById('category').value;
var creator= document.getElementById('creator').value;
var type= document.getElementById('type').value;
var datetime= document.getElementById('datetime').value;
var sex= document.getElementById('sex').value;
var grade= document.getElementById('grade').value;
var message= document.getElementById('message').value;
var announcement = {
Title: title,
Category: category,
Creator: creator,
Type: type,
DateTime: datetime,
Sex: sex,
Grade: grade,
Message: message
};
var x = JSON.stringify(announcement);
localStorage.setItem('announcement', x); 
}

function showAnnouncement(){
var obj = localStorage.getItem('announcement').value;
var obj2 = JSON.parse (obj);

document.getElementById('showAnnouncement').innerHTML = "title:" + obj2.title 
+  "category:" + obj2.category + "creator:" + obj2.creator + "type:" + 
obj2.type + "datetime:" + obj2.datetime + "sex:" + obj2.sex + "grade:" + 
obj2.grade + "message:" + obj2.message;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors on your logic here.

Since your input is created as `type="submit"`, it will try to do a HTTP POST instead of calling your `createAnnouncement()` function. You can change it to `type="button"`.

After that, you need to find a way to trigger the `showAnnouncement()` function, this could be an element such as an `<a>` or another `<button>`.